# Calling eBay API from jmeter returns: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: jmeter, sandbox, ebay-api

I have problem specially with jmeter and Ebay. Jmeter is working with different API and eBay payload is working with Postman client. But I need to create some items in eBay from jmeter. Used jmeter 2.9 and also 2.13 same result.

I used sample from [developer.ebay](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#samplebasic)

This is the request sent out by jmeter:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

POST https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll

POST data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>mytoken***</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Item>
    <Title>Potters Father looks for Anakin</Title>
    <Description>
      This is the first book in the Harry Potter series. In excellent condition!
    </Description>
    <PrimaryCategory>
      <CategoryID>377</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <StartPrice>1.0</StartPrice>
    <CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>
    <ConditionID>4000</ConditionID>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>Chinese</ListingType>
    <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
    <PayPalEmailAddress>***@126.com</PayPalEmailAddress>
    <PictureDetails>
      <PictureURL>http://pics.ebay.com/aw/pics/dot_clear.gif</PictureURL>
    </PictureDetails>
    <PostalCode>95125</PostalCode>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ReturnPolicy>
      <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
      <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
      <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
      <Description>If you are not satisfied, return the book for refund.</Description>
      <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
    </ReturnPolicy>
    <ShippingDetails>
      <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
      <ShippingServiceOptions>
        <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
        <ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>
        <ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>
      </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <Site>US</Site>
  </Item>
</AddItemRequest>

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/xml
Content-Type: application/xml
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: 889
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: AddItem
X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: ***
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: ***
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: ***
Content-Length: 2762
```

This is java stack jmeter returned:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(HttpSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:151)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:258)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Did you somebody did similar scenario? I dont know where is the problem, both parts jmeter also sample addItem call are working separately. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again by removing below in your payload and post it again, I hope it should work .

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`    ,

also please attach the jmeter http sampler screenshot.

debugging tips:

1. if it works in POST MAN , try to find the difference in http raw request went in both  .
   If you find any try adding adding them in jmeter too , sometime http headers
   will miss.
2. check your machine is firewall protected?

   Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you for answer. 2. was near, Its embarrassing for me but I forgot that Im behind proxy. Payload was same like POST MAN, with proxy it worked. So Im moving forward. Thanks

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. if it solves, please make this as answered